# How can I replace part of list and have the replacement affect the initial list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
list = {{1,1,0.05,0.05}, {2,2,0.05,0.05}};
```

and I want to do this change

```
Replace[#[[1]], #[[1]] -> (#[[1]] + #[[3]])]& /@ list    
Replace[#[[2]], #[[2]] -> (#[[2]] + #[[4]])]& /@ list
```

The problem is that the initial list doesn't change.

My list represents  $\{\{x, y, v_x, v_y\}, \{x, y, v_x,  v_y\}\} $ and 
I want to use a replacement rule to change the position of the objects and 
thereby represent movement.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend to apply certain function (here you'd like `{#1 + #3, #2 + #4, #3, #4} &`) at the level `1` of the list ( `f @@@ list` is a shorthand for `Apply[ f, list, {1}]`). So here a good way is :

```
list = {{1, 1, 0.05, 0.05}, {2, 2, 0.05, 0.05}};

list = {#1 + #3, #2 + #4, #3, #4} & @@@ list
```

> ```
> {{1.05, 1.05, 0.05, 0.05}, {2.05, 2.05, 0.05, 0.05}}
> ```

If you want to play with `ReplaceAll` you can try another approach, e.g. this :

```
list = list /. {a_, b_, c_, d_} -> {a + c, b + d, c, d}
```

it yields the same list :

```
(list /. {a_, b_, c_, d_} -> {a + c, b + d, c, d}) == ({#1 + #3, #2 + #4, #3, #4} & @@@ list)
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you may have misunderstood the meaning of `Replace`. It doesn't replace anything in the sense of modifying the object on which it acts. It produces a *new* object. So what you really want to do if you want `list` to change is this:

```
list = {{1, 1, 0.05, 0.05}, {2, 2, 0.05, 0.05}}

(* ==> {{1, 1, 0.05, 0.05}, {2, 2, 0.05, 0.05}} *)

list = {#[[1]] + #[[3]], #[[2]] + #[[4]], #[[3]], #[[4]]} & /@
   list

(* ==> {{1.05, 1.05, 0.05, 0.05}, {2.05, 2.05, 0.05, 0.05}} *)
```

Then you can repeatedly apply the last assignment to represent the movement in the first two components.

Here I have explicitly assigned the result of the `Map` operation on `list` back to the variable `list` itself by using `Set` (`list = ...`).